# Shell complains 'cannot execute binary file'

Tags: linux, shell

I've playing around with linux and noticed that for some mysterious reason commands like '/bin/sh ' just will not work. Each time I'm trying to start a process it yields 'cannot execute binary file' error message.

```
m@sanctuary:~$ sh sed
/bin/sed: /bin/sed: cannot execute binary file
```

When I first launch sh and try to execute sed, it succeeds.

I'm starting to lose my wits. It would be just great, if somebody could help me.

Thank you.

Comment: "sed" isn't a shell script, so you don't execute it with sh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"sed" isn't a shell script, so you don't execute it with sh.  Just type `sed ...args...` not `sh sed ...args...`

Comment: Or if you really want to run it through `sh` for some reason you can use `sh -c sed`.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to run sed as a shell script, sed is just an ordinary executable. You can just run it as

```
m@sanctuary:~$ sed
```

Answer (score 0):

`sh` is expecting a shell script as an argument, but you're giving it a binary file.